Получение аватара пользователя из Django OAuth Discord
Столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю откуда взять url аватара пользователя, когда он регистрируется через Discord.
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div class="user-info">
    <img style="z-index: 9099;" src="{{ user.avatar.url }}"></img>
    <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
                
    <a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}" class="logout-button">Logout</a>
  </div>
{% else %}

То есть если по логике то можно было бы взять {{ user.username }} и преобразовать {{ user.avatar.url }}, но это похоже работает не так.
Написано при регистрации, что бот к которому привязан OAuth, имеет доступ к аватару пользователя, но я не знаю как его получить, и информации не нашёл(
